# Running many files in Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I get made code files running at the same time in VS code app?
When I run say `my_pomodoro_app.py` which comes with a Tkinter window, I am unable to run any other code file unless I close my pomodoro app. This does not happen in Pycharm.

Is that how VS code works? Or I have to do some settings to enable running mmany programs?

I search on the internet but coudn't get the solution

Comment: In Visual Studio Code, by default, only one Python file can run at a time in a terminal. To run multiple files simultaneously, you need to open multiple terminals in Visual Studio Code and run each file in a separate terminal.

Here's how you can do it:

Open the terminal in Visual Studio Code by clicking on View -> Terminal.
Right-click in the terminal and select New Terminal.
In each terminal, navigate to the directory containing the Python file you want to run.

Comment: The `Run Python File` and `Debug Python File` buttons coming with **Microsoft Python extension** only issue commands in the extension's one and only terminal. When you tried to run another Python script with previous one running, the `python another_file.py` command was sent to stdin of your pomodoro app.

Comment: do you want to Run multiple Python scripts or do you want to Debug multiple Python scripts, for debug you can use multiple Tasks that start multiple debuggers and then use an attach to debugger launch configuration multiple times, to run just use multiple tasks